# Why is the distanceFromLocation: method returning a ridiculous number

Tags: ios, gps

I'm trying to calculate and return the distance between two points and I'm getting a ridiculous number. I've tried both a user-defined haversine method and the distanceFromLocation method and they are both returning 10282657.652... for the distance between lat = 32.60641072/ lon = -85.48713530 and lat = 32.605638 and lon = -85.486890. Are these distances too close?

```
CLLocation *startLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude      longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

    CLLocation *endLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:_head.lattitude  longitude:_head.longitude];
    double distance = [startLocation distanceFromLocation:endLocation];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordinate = [startLocation coordinate];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D oldCoordinate = [endLocation coordinate];
    double distance2 = [self distanceFrom:newCoordinate to:oldCoordinate];
    NSNumber *myDoubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:distance2];

    _charLabel.text = [myDoubleNumber stringValue];
```

Comment: Maybe it's because for `startLocation`, the code is passing `latitude` for the `longitude` parameter.

Comment: I'm an idiot. That was the first thing I checked and completely missed that. Thank YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:lon1];
CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:lon2];
CLLocationDistance distance= [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2]*1.09361;
```

"distance" will return on meter.
This code worked for me :)